# Append intended target URL when user is not authenticated with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently using a `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` with targetUrlParameter as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login**", "/actuator/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
        .and()
        .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .rememberMe().key(token).tokenValiditySeconds(validity)
        .userDetailsService(service)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
  }

  public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
  }

  public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    handler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirect");

    return handler;
  }
}
```

But when I try to navigate to any URL without being authenticated such as [http://localhost:8080/some-protected-url](http://localhost:8080) I would expect to be redirected to [http://localhost:8080/login?redirect=some-protected-url](http://localhost:8080) but the `redirect` parameter doesn't get appended to the URL.

What's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the redirect, [the URL is stored server-side in a `RequestCache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-exceptiontranslationfilter). The default request cache is `HttpSessionRequestCache`.

Generally speaking, it's preferable to [store the URL server-side to avoid Open Redirect](https://portswigger.net/kb/issues/00500100_open-redirection-reflected) vulnerabilities.